# Receiving error code when non unique value is found in list

Tags: python, error-handling

So our assignment is to find non unique items on our list and return an error message if two "students" havde the same student id number. 
"Your program must at least detect and display information about the following possible errors:
1. If two students in the data have the same student id.
2. If a grade in the data set is not one of the possible grades on the 7-step-scale [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]."

The list is an n x m matrix, where n is the amount of students and m is the amount of assignments. [image: Example of matrix] Now we know that len normally can be used to compare the length of vectors, so at first we tried the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Funktioner:

#Oploadfunktion:

grades = pd.read_csv("mads.csv", sep=",")
grades1=np.array(grades)   
sid=grades1[:,0]   
myset= set(sid)
a=np.size(grades1[:,0])
b=np.size(grades1[0,:]) 
grades2=np.array(grades.iloc[0:a,2:b])


if len(myset)<len(sid):
    print("Student Id used twice")
else: print("All good in the hood")
for i in grades2[i]:
    if i in grades2[i] != **[-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]**:
        print("Grades not valid")
        break
    else:
        print("All good in the hood")
```

We know the first part of the code tells us if the student id is used twice, but does not identify where, or the degree to which it happens. The second part of the assignment, as you see, we are completly lost. We apreciate all help.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your grade-list like so:

```
for grade in grades2:
```

In every iteration, variable grade is compared against all variables in the allowed grade list like so:

```
    if grade not in [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]:
```

So the complete code is:

```
for grade in grades2:
    if grade not in [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]:
        print("Grades not valid, {:}".format(grade))
        break
    else:
        print("All good in the hood")
```

Comment: When I try the code i get ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(), back. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: I dont get one. What are you passing to the grades2 list? What python version are you using ?